# Laptop battery stopped working suddenly

Tags: battery, thinkpad

My laptop battery used to last 2-3hrs, and from one day to another its autonomy dropped to 15 mins, and a few hours later it wasn't functioning at all any more (as soon as I unplug the power cord, the laptop turns off).

I did some research online, and people say that a battery autonomy drops little by little, but that it is rare that it stops working like that, and that it could be a system issue.

The battery icon always says *currently estimating charge*.

I got a Thinkpad T520 and I'm on Ubuntu 18.10. I updated my system to the latest version hoping that it would solve the problem, but it didn't.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem count be?

Comment: Sounds like hardware (battery) failure.

Comment: If resetting EC is not working, the battery is dead.

Comment: Hardware questions are off topic on this SE -- you might look for a suitable SE that covers either battery technology or computer hardware.

Comment: Remove the AC. Unplug the internal battery. Hold down the power button for 10-15 seconds. Reconnect the internal battery and AC, and retest. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: hello @heynnema , I just tried it and it didn't change anything. Thanks for the tip anyways!

Answer (score 2):

It could be a faulty battery :( 
You can install tlp `sudo apt install tlp`
once installed start it with this command `sudo tlp start`
Then you can check the battery stats with this command `sudo tlp-stat --battery`
that should tell you what condition it's in. 
good luck,

[here is a link](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html#commands) to all the commands for tlp.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
The battery status is :
Charge                                                      =   51.5 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   73.6 [%]

So it's as if the battery was actually half charged, that's weird.

Comment: Have you checked the charger also the wires are some times quite fragile.

Comment: yeah, I actually tried with another charger and nothing changed. I guess it's not a software issue after all, my battery must be broken.